# Flex 4 - Adding a dynamic transparent mask

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, masking

What I was trying to achieve is a simple masking in flex but I am not getting it right or getting right approach. I am not even sure if it is possible by using just masking methods.

I need to mask the complete mc and allow the user to view only a particular rectangular spot.

I did it using code below (slightly different from original code)

```
  var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
  var g:Graphics = uc.graphics;         
  g.beginFill(0xff000,0.5);
  g.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
  g.endFill();
  s.x = 50;
  s.y = 50;
  obj.addChild(s);
  obj.mask = s;
```

Above code creates a 100x100 rectangle and is applied as mask to the obj which is another movieclip.

This works fine, Here I slightly want to change the normal behavior of the masking. Which is by making the masked area (the inaccessible area) transparent instead completely hide it.

Is it possible?

**Update**:

Adding complete modified flex code based on Baris Uskli's suggestions:

**MaskView.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" left="0" top="0" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="showMask()"
         blendMode="layer">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <!--<s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x00aabb" alpha="0.5" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>-->
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            //public static var app:Object;
            //private var
            public var conf:LightBoxConfiguration;

            public function showMask():void{

                this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.6);
                this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
                this.graphics.endFill();

                var uc:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uc.mouseEnabled = false;

                var g:Graphics = uc.graphics;

                g.beginFill(0xff000,0.5);

                if (conf.shape == "box"){

                    uc.width = conf.width;
                    uc.height = conf.height;
                    //TODO:need to fix this
                    g.drawRect(0,0,conf.width,conf.height);

                }else{

                    uc.width = conf.radius*2;
                    uc.height = conf.radius*2;

                    g.drawCircle(0,0,conf.radius);
                }
                g.endFill();

                uc.x = conf.x;
                uc.y = conf.y;
                uc.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
                this.addElement(uc);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

caller

```
            var lbc:LightBoxConfiguration = new LightBoxConfiguration("box",100,100);

            lbc.height = 200;
            lbc.width = 300;

            var msk:MaskView = new MaskView();

            msk.conf = lbc;
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(msk);
```

This is giving the expected effect but unfortunately I am unable to click through the rectangle area. I have set mouseEnabled = false; also but it did not work. I think I am few steps far from achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using BlendModes. Here is some code that draws a fullscreen transparent sprite and the masks a rectangular area in it.

```
private function mask():void
{
   this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.6);
   this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
   this.graphics.endFill();

   var maskSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
   maskSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
   maskSprite.graphics.drawRect(x,y,width,height);
   maskSprite.graphics.endFill();

   addChild(maskSprite);

   this.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
   maskSprite.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: Some sorcery to only make the mask area clickable, not perfect but maybe someone can improve. You can paste the whole thing in an empty Flex 4 app and try clicking on the button through the mask or over the gray area, on the masked area will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="showMask()"
           addedToStage="onAddedToStage()"
           >

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button label="test" x="140" y="120" click="onButtonClicked(event)"></s:Button>

<s:Group id="maskGroup" blendMode="layer"  width="800" height="600" ></s:Group>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.display.DisplayObject;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.geom.Point;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        private var uc:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

        private function onAddedToStage():void
        {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClicked, true);
        }

        private function onButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("clicked button");
        }

        private function onMouseClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var objects:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));
            var clickedInMask:Boolean = false;
            for each (var dp:DisplayObject in objects) 
            {
                if (dp == uc)
                {
                    clickedInMask = true;
                    break;
                }
            }               
            if(!clickedInMask)
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        }

        private function showMask():void
        {
            maskGroup.mouseEnabled = false;
            maskGroup.mouseChildren = false;


            var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sp.graphics.clear();
            sp.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.6);
            sp.graphics.drawRect(0,0,800,600);
            sp.graphics.endFill();

            var spC:UIComponent =  new UIComponent();
            spC.addChild(sp);
            maskGroup.addElement(spC);

            uc.x = 100;
            uc.y = 100;
            maskGroup.addElement(uc);

            var g:Graphics = uc.graphics;

            g.beginFill(0xffffff,1);

            g.drawRect(0,0,100,100);

            g.endFill();                

            uc.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I am unable to click through the rectangle hole (mask). I have set mouseEnabled to false to allow it to ignore the clicks but it is not working. I have added the complete code which was originally written for flex using as3. Can you please help?

Comment: If you set mouseEnabled to false no mouse events will be dispatched, you might want to catch all mouse clicks on the sprite and then stop the ones that are not in the rectangle area by event.stopImmediatePropagation()

Comment: I actually want the same masking behaviour expect that I need to show the sourrounding with transparent color.
I was expecting that if I disable the mouseevents of maskSprites then it will click the objects underneath but it is not.

Comment: Hmm maybe try setting mouseEnabled and mouseChildren false on MaskView, not sure if that will help you though.

Comment: Unfortunately that making every thing clickable making concept of mask just for only highlighting the area :(  I tried some more combination of mouseenable and disable but none has worked :(

Comment: If you're close to what you want visually, then for the mouse events maybe you can add a layer on top of all of these objects to handle the mouse events where you want them.